# aws vpc endpoints - how it works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am trying to understand the concept of how VPC endpoints work and I am not sure that I understand the AWS documentation. For example, I have a private S3 bucket and I have an EKS cluster. So if my bucket is private I believe that traffic from the EKS cluster to S3 does not go through the internet, but only through the AWS network. But in a case my s3 bucket was public, then probably I will need to set up the VPC endpoint, so traffic will not leave the AWS. The same logic I would expect with ECR, if it is private you load images to your EKS through AWS network.
So what is the exact case when you need to use VPC endpoint within your AWS account (not from on-prem or another VPC)?

Comment: If you want to guarantee that traffic from your EKS cluster reaches your S3 bucket via AWS private networking, rather than the public internet, then configure and use a VPC endpoint for Amazon S3 in that VPC. The terms 'private bucket' and 'public bucket' aren't well-defined but they typically relate to the requirement, or not, for authentication/authorization, rather than network routing.

Answer (score 3):

VPC endpoints are typically used with *public* AWS services (such as S3, DynamoDB, ECR, etc.) when the client applications are hosted inside your VPC and you do not want to route traffic via public Internet, which would otherwise result in a number of hops to reach the AWS service.

Imagine a situation when you have an app running on an EC2 instance, which is deployed to a private subnet of your VPC (i.e. a Pod in your EKS cluster). This app reads/writes data from/to AWS S3. If you **do not** use a VPC endpoint, your traffic will first reach your NAT gateway, then your VPC's Internet gateway out to the public Internet. Eventually, it will hit AWS S3. The response will travel back via the same route.

Same thing with ECR (i.e. a new instance of your Kubernetes Pod started by the `kubelet`). It's better (i.e. *quicker*) to pick the shortest route to download a Docker image from ECR rather than traverse a number of switches/routers. **With** a VPC endpoint your traffic will first hit the VPC endpoint (without leaving your private subnet) and then reach e.g. `ECR` directly (traffic does not leave the Amazon network).

As correctly mentioned by `@jarmod`, one should differentiate between **routing** (*Layer 3* in the OSI model) and **authentication/authorization** (*Layer 7*). For example, you can use a VPC endpoint to reach AWS S3, but not be authorized (or even unauthenticated) to e.g. read a file from an S3 bucket.

Hope this clarifies the idea behind using VPC endpoints.